# Comment choisir parmi les verbes « percevoir », « se percevoir », « apercevoir » et « s'apercevoir » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Prière de faire ressortir les points communs et les divergences entre ces quatre verbes ? Certes, je sais que « se + ... » est un verbe pronominal. Je ne peux trouver aucune ressource qui en discourt. Par exemple, Wordreference [ici](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/apercevoir%20percevoir) et [là](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/apercevoir) ne traite que le cas de « percevoir » et « apercevoir ».

Comment: Si tu observe attentivement l’entrée [apercevoir](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/apercevoir) de WordReference, tu pourras voir deux acception pour s’apercevoir. Pour « se percevoir » (et, d’ailleurs, une autre utilisation de «s’apercevoir ») Tu peux également t’intéresser à l’entrée [se](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/se).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percevoir = 'Perceive' as in 'I perceive footsteps in the distance.' = 'Je perçois des (bruits de) pas au loin.'

Se percevoir = 'Perceive oneself' as in 'I don't perceive myself as being fat.' = 'Je ne me perçois pas comme quelqu'un de gros.'

Apercevoir = 'Seeing something/someone in an unaccurate manner' as in 'I (barely) saw her as she was away.' = 'Je l'ai aperçue alors qu'elle s'en allait.'

S'apercevoir = 'Realize' as in 'I realized I didn't have my cellphone.' = 'Je me suis aperçu que je n'avais pas mon téléphone portable.'

It should be noted that "S'apercevoir" can also be used as "Apercevoir" towards oneself, as in "Je me suis aperçu dans le mirroir." = "I saw myself in the mirror."

Comment: Pourquoi diable répondre exclusivement en anglais (et entièrement à travers des traduction) à une question en français ?

Comment: Parce qu'il est bien plus facile de faire comprendre des distinctions de ce genre en utilisant directement une phrase de la langue maternelle de celui qui pose la question. De plus, cela aide aussi plus rapidement les personnes qui, se posant la même question, tomberont sur cette question et ne baisseront pas les bras parce qu'ils ne se trouvent pas face à un mur de français.

Comment: @GabrielTheron Un mur de français ? Si le problème c'est le français, la personne est sur le mauvais site me semble-t-il... Si le problème c'est que la réponse ressemble à un mur, libre à nous d'écrire des réponses courtes, précises, et d'utiliser des styles. Pour rejoindre Edouard, je pense moi aussi que la question, formulée en français, appelait une réponse en français. L'idéal étant une réponse bilingue, proposant les deux versions ;-)

Comment: N.B. Apercevoir et s'apercevoir ne se construisent pas de la même façon avec leur complément : on aperçoit qqch mais on s'aperçoit **de** qqch.