# Du coin de l’œil, j’aperçois / perçois A et B

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

> Du coin de l’œil, j’**aperçois** A et B qui essaient d’ouvrir l’armoire
> fermée à clé.
>
> Du coin de l’œil, je **perçois** A et B qui essaient d’ouvrir l’armoire
> fermée à clé.

D'après Antidote, **percevoir** :

> Saisir par les sens. *Percevoir un son, une lumière*.

Donc, les deux phrases sont possibles, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: J'ai vu ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/comment-choisir-parmi-les-verbes-percevoir-se-percevoir-apercevoir), mais j'ai toujours des doutes.

Answer (score 3):

La deux phrases sont possibles mais la première l'est plus que la deuxième.

***[Percevoir](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/percevoir)*** est plus vague car tous les sens peuvent être impliqués dans une perception, voire même autre chose comme l'intuition, tandis que seule la vue est concernée avec ***[apercevoir](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/apercevoir)***.

Comme la phrase indique que c'est de la vue qu'il s'agit (*du coin de l'**œil***) et que ce qui est perçu est décrit avec assez de précision (*tentative d'ouverture d'une armoire*), la phrase avec ***apercevoir*** paraît bien plus indiquée.