# Differences between (s')apercevoir vs. (se) percevoir. Disregard the sense of percevoir “sans effort d’attention, ni recherche"

Tags: différence

Disregard the sense of « [Voir quelqu'un, quelque chose que l'éloignement, la petitesse de l'objet, l'obscurité, etc., empêchent de découvrir à première vue, entrevoir un instant](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/apercevoir/4421#definition) », because this is exclusive to *apercevoir*. I know *apercevoir* [= *a + percevoir*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/apercevoir).

I read [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8271), but I still cannot distinguish these cognates! The following senses of *apercevoir* look identical to *percevoir*! In EACH following sentence, I feel that *(s')apercevoir* CAN ACCURATELY + PRECISELY REPLACE `(se) percevoir` without changing meaning. Am I correct? Why, or why not?

#### Examples from [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/apercevoir/4421#definition)

> **2. Voir quelque chose plus ou moins nettement :** L'eau est très claire : on `aperçoit` le fond de la rivière.

#### Examples from [Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/apercevoir)

> **1.  Voir plus ou moins nettement. ➙ discerner, distinguer.** On `apercevait` au loin le village.
>
> **3.  Saisir par l'esprit.** J'`aperçois` bien ses intentions. ➙ comprendre, deviner.

#### Examples from [CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapproche)

> [I.][A.] Rem. 1. Apercevoir au part. prés. est employé fréq. dans les notations scéniques. 2. Apercevoir peut se construire avec un attribut de l'obj. (ex. 6).
> − Insolite. [Suivi de l'inf., p. anal. avec voir + inf.] :
>
> > 7. Il vénérait Verhaeren. (...) Il aimait, (...) en retrouver à tout instant les larges visions tragiques : le moulin, dont les bras, ... comme des bras de plainte, se sont tendus, et sont tombés ... Les astres qui, là-haut, semblent les feux de grands cierges, tenus en main, dont on n'`aperçoit` pas monter la tige immense. Van der Meersch, *L'Empreinte du dieu*, 1936, p. 141.

> ## II.− Emploi pronom.
>
> ## A.− Emploi trans.
>
> ### 1. Emploi réfl. S'apercevoir (dans la glace) :
>
> > 16. Je `m'aperçus` dans cette glace et je puis dire que j'ai vu une fois en ma vie l'image accomplie de la stupéfaction. A. France, *Le Crime de Sylvestre Bonnard*,1881, p. 124.
>
> − P. ext. Se découvrir, prendre conscience de soi :
>
> > 17. `Nous apercevons-nous` mieux dans le bonheur que dans le malheur? Dans le bonheur nous ne trouvons que nous; dans le malheur, nous découvrons les autres. Maeterlinck, *L'Ombre des ailes*, 1936, p. 70.
>
> ### 2. Emploi réciproque :
>
> > 18. La salle commençait à se remplir, on tirait les lorgnettes de leurs étuis, et les abonnés, `s'apercevant` de loin, se faisaient des salutations. Flaubert, *Madame Bovary*, t. 2, 1857, p. 65.
>
> ### 3. Emploi pronom. passif. Être aperçu, être saisi par la vue :
>
> > 19. Son vêtement presque misérable ne `s'apercevait` pas dans l'obscurité que faisait l'abat-jour. On ne distinguait que son visage calme et grave, mais étrangement triste. Hugo, *Les Misérables*,t. 2, 1862, p. 246.
>
> − Au fig. :
>
> > 20. Les résultats de la critique ne se prouvent pas, ils `s'aperçoivent`; ils exigent pour être compris un long exercice et toute une culture de finesse. Renan, *L'Avenir de la science*, 1890, p. 298.

Comment: I feel there are two issues in your question. *Apercevoir* vs *percevoir* and *s'apercevoir* vs *se percevoir*.  On the one side we deal with transitive verbs that require a direct object, on the other side we deal with pronominal verbs that can either have a reciprocal meaning or a passive meaning. For example can you perceive the difference between *J'aperçois le village du haut de la montagne* &  *Le village s'aperçoit du haut de la montage* where *apercevoir* and *percevoir* are not interchangeable.

Comment: "For example can you perceive the difference"? No, sorry. Why not « *Je PERÇOIS le village du haut de la montagne* »? Why not « *Le village se PERÇOIT du haut de la montage* »?

Comment: Yes you could have  *je perçois le village du haut de la montagne* and *le village se perçoit du haut de la montagne*, the express different meanings ? Sorry in my previous comment it should read "where *apercevoir and s'apercevoir* are not interchangeable".

Comment: @None Je suis encore déboussolée. Je n'**(a???)perçois** pas les "différentes significations" dans « Je PERÇOIS le village du haut de la montagne », « Le village se PERÇOIT du haut de la montage ».

Comment: You wouldn't say "le village se perçoit…", but instead "Le village s'aperçoit…" (pronominal passif). You don't find "perçoit le village": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aper%C3%A7oit+le+village%2Cper%C3%A7oit+le+village%2Cpercevait+le+village&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3 , https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=village+s%27aper%C3%A7oit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @LPH On pourrait dire "le village se perçoit comme une entité autonome". Ou bien "il perçoit le village comme un refuge".

Comment: @Frank Oui mais ça n'aurait plus rien à voir avec les sens ; on aurait à considérer la définition « saisir, prendre connaissance par l'intuition, par l'entendement » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/percevoir))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Percevoir", as a verb having to do with cognition, has two main senses ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/percevoir)).

> A.− Saisir, prendre connaissance par les sens. Percevoir une couleur, une odeur, un son.  [**D1**]
> B.− Saisir, prendre connaissance par l'intuition ou par l'entendement. Synon. discerner, saisir  [**D2**]

The literal sense of "apercevoir" is not to be considered ("Voir quelqu'un, quelque chose que l'éloignement, la petitesse de l'objet, l'obscurité, etc., empêchent de découvrir à première vue, entrevoir un instant"); it is sense "**I A**" in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apercevoir).

> A.− Saisir par la vue, en un instant, une personne ou une chose, en dépit de certains obstacles, en particulier l'éloignement, le rétrécissement du champ de vision, le manque de luminosité.
>
> 1. Le plus souvent. Après un effort d'attention ou après quelque recherche. Synon. découvrir
> 2. Plus rarement. Sans effort d'attention, ni recherche

It comprises senses "1" and "2" in both the Larousse and the Robert; in fact "1" and "2" in these dictionaries are merely aspects of one main meaning which is literal; we'll refer to it as "**D3**" in what follows; What concerns us is then what's left, that is, sense "**I B**", the figurative sense.

> B.− Au fig. Saisir une chose abstraite (la qualité de quelque chose, un fait, ...) par l'esprit (après quelque recherche). Synon. se rendre compte (de) [**D4**]

---

1. L'eau est très claire : on aperçoit le fond de la rivière.

In this first case the natural definition is "D3" (1); warning: the synonym is for instance, "discerner"; the unique synonym given by the TLFi does not constitute a sufficient list (they only take care of one case) and it is not quite proper in this case. Why is not "D1" proper, not a synonym?

"Percevoir" is a verb at the same time much more encompassing than "apercevoir" and much more basic: "apercevoir" has to do with just one of the senses, sight, whereas "percevoir" has to do with all the senses, even those that we, humans, do not have, and even "senses" which are not that of the mind but plainly what you have to call "sensors".

- L'œil humain [perçoit les ondes électromagnétiques](https://lenalighting.fr/?catid=0&id=1949) dans une plage très restreinte de fréquences très hautes.
- La chauve-souris perçoit les distances par le biais des ultra-sons.
- Les pigeons perçoivent l'orientation du champs magnétique de la terre.
- Les mammifères, comme beaucoup d'autres créatures perçoivent les chose grâce au sens de la vue.

If "percevoir" does apply to sight too, it does so in a simple way, merely as the bacic components of space and the things in it are concerned.

- Lœil perçoit les angles, les surfaces, les couleurs, l'intensité des couleurs, la profondeur du champ de vision.

The action considered in "apercevoir" is the result of an application of all these perceptions, it  is a much more complicated thing.

- On dit donc « percevoir un bruit » mais pas « percevoir une symphonie », et de même « percevoir le rouge du clocher du village » mais pas « percevoir le village ».

2. Il vénérait Verhaeren. (...) Il aimait, (...) en retrouver à tout instant les larges visions tragiques : le moulin, dont les bras, ... comme des bras de plainte, se sont tendus, et sont tombés ... Les astres qui, là-haut, semblent les feux de grands cierges, tenus en main, dont on n'`aperçoit` pas monter la tige immense. Van der Meersch, L'Empreinte du dieu, 1936, p. 141.

Il devrait être clair que, d'après ce qui a été dit au "1.", "percevoir" ne convient pas.

3. Je m'`aperçus` dans cette glace et je puis dire que j'ai vu une fois en ma vie l'image accomplie de la stupéfaction. A. France, Le Crime de Sylvestre Bonnard,1881, p. 124.

Same context as above

4. `Nous apercevons-nous` mieux dans le bonheur que dans le malheur? Dans le bonheur nous ne trouvons que nous; dans le malheur, nous découvrons les autres. Maeterlinck, L'Ombre des ailes, 1936, p. 70.

This is a figurative sense, and the figurative aspect of "percevoir" makes it perhaps a synonym because it can be applied to  complex ensembles.

5. La salle commençait à se remplir, on tirait les lorgnettes de leurs étuis, et les abonnés, `s'apercevant` de loin, se faisaient des salutations. Flaubert, Madame Bovary, t. 2, 1857, p. 65.

Here we get back in the domain of the literal and therefore to the beginning ("1.", 2.", "3").

6. Son vêtement presque misérable ne s'apercevait pas dans l'obscurité que faisait l'abat-jour. On ne distinguait que son visage calme et grave, mais étrangement triste. Hugo, Les Misérables,t. 2, 1862, p. 246.

As in "5."

7. Les résultats de la critique ne se prouvent pas, ils s'aperçoivent; ils exigent pour être compris un long exercice et toute une culture de finesse. Renan, L'Avenir de la science, 1890, p. 298.

As in "4"

Answer (score 1):

> J'aperçois le village du haut de la montagne.

*Je* is the subject of *apercevoir* which is a transitive verb and *le village* is the direct object of the verb.

> Le village s'aperçoit du haut de la montagne.

In this last sentence *s'apercevoir* is a pronominal verb with a passive meaning. *Le village* is the subject of the verb.

Even if the action is the same in both sentences, the point of view is different. It is a choice of wanting or not to name the subject. In English the sentence would be translated with the passive ("the village can be seen..." vs "one can see the village...").

It's the same with *percevoir*: *Je perçois de l'angoisse dans sa voix* vs *l'angoisse qu'elle traverse se perçoit dans sa voix*.

The difference between *apercevoir* and *percevoir* should be a different question.